# Click event for the wrong button being fired in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This happens very rarely but it still happens sometimes. I have two buttons next to each others with a jQuery click event on each:

**JS:**

```
$("#accepttrade").click(function(){
    if(document.getElementById("agreeterms").checked ){
        //accept process
        $("#acceptdeposit").slideUp(200);
    }

});

$("#declinetrade").click(function(){
    //decline
    $("#acceptdeposit").slideUp(200);

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="acceptdeposit">
    <button id="declinetrade" >Decline</button>&emsp;
    <button id="accepttrade" >Accept</button><input type="checkbox" id="agreeterms">
</div>
```

But sometimes when someone click on decline, it occurs the click of accept button, and go through even if the checkbox is unchecked.

I have never experienced it myself, but is it possible that this could happend? How can I be sure that "accept process" is never reached unless the user checks the box and click on accept?

Comment: I think you'll need to wrap the function click assignment in a document.ready function. Otherwise it's trying to assign the first click before the button is rendered

Comment: Either that or assign the click event in the button html markup

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the click events are already in an document.ready function

Comment: @Matthew Flynn do you mean something like: <button onclick="myFunction()"> ?

Comment: Is it possible to have more precisions for "sometimes" ? It happens in all browers ? In which context ? Pointing or touch device ?

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, jQuery event binding is preferred.

Comment: Do you do anything to move IDs around dynamically? Or do you have any duplicate IDs on the page? I can't think of any other reason why this would happen.

Comment: @Michel It happens with all type of browser, even with chrome. on devices like computers.

Comment: Can you make a [Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Barmar The ids are not changing, but I call a socket with the same name: socket.emit('accepttrade') but it shouldn't impact the button

Comment: You're right, it shouldn't. To diagnose this you need to post enough that we can actually try it and see the problem. Please make a fiddle.

Comment: It seems like it could be a browser/plugin issue here. [Works fine in this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdh6wq0j/). You cannot ever be **sure** that the checkbox is checked when someone presses Accept. Because they can alter your javascript code client side and force it to go through without checking the box.

Comment: I agree it seems odd. I see no issue in your markup. Are you including any other jquery plugins which maybe using the generated ids?

Comment: I am using a customscrollbar jquery, and bootstrap, but that's it. The event is situated in a very big function document.ready (maybe it's the problem?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, cancel your click event:

```
$("#accepttrade").click(function(e){
   if($("#agreeterms").is(':checked') ){
       //accept process
       $("#acceptdeposit").slideUp(200);
   }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```